# I want to change the look of the span id to look like an input box but display numbers?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on this simple html challenge and got all the code that I need to calculate everything, however I want to change the look of the span id's to look like input boxes like the one shown with "Cost of dinner" This is my code;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Tip Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
    </header>
    <form action="javascript:void(calc())">
        Cost of the Dinner: $<input id="bill" type="text">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate Tip">
        <br>
        15% of the Dinner: <span id="tip"></span>
        <br>
        25% of the Dinner: <span id="tip2"></span>
        <br>
        Dinner plus 25% tip: <span id="total"></span>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    function calc() {
        var bill = Number(document.getElementById('bill').value);
        var tip = bill * .15;
        var tip2= bill * .25;
        var total_bill = bill + tip2;

        document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML= "$"+Number(tip).toFixed(2);
         document.getElementById("tip2").innerHTML= "$"+Number(tip2).toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML= "$"+Number(total_bill).toFixed(2);         
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
function calc() {
    var bill = Number(document.getElementById('bill').value);
    var tip = bill * .15;
    var tip2= bill * .25;
    var total_bill = bill + tip2;

    document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML= "$"+Number(tip).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("tip2").innerHTML= "$"+Number(tip2).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML= "$"+Number(total_bill).toFixed(2);         
}
```

```css
form > span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
  border: 0.5px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
    </header>
    <form action="javascript:void(calc())">
        Cost of the Dinner: $<input id="bill" type="text">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate Tip">
        <br>
        15% of the Dinner: <span id="tip"></span>
        <br>
        25% of the Dinner: <span id="tip2"></span>
        <br>
        Dinner plus 25% tip: <span id="total"></span>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Edits:**

This fixes the vertical alignment between the spanbox and the label.

```js
function calc() {
        var bill = Number(document.getElementById('bill').value);
        var tip = bill * .15;
        var tip2= bill * .25;
        var total_bill = bill + tip2;

        document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML= "$"+Number(tip).toFixed(2);
         document.getElementById("tip2").innerHTML= "$"+Number(tip2).toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML= "$"+Number(total_bill).toFixed(2);         
    }
```

```css
form p:not(:first-child) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

form > p > span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
  border: 0.5px solid gray;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
    </header>
    <form action="javascript:void(calc())">
      <p>
        Cost of the Dinner: $<input id="bill" type="text">
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate Tip">
      </p>
      <p>
        15% of the Dinner: <span id="tip"></span>
      </p>
      <p>
        25% of the Dinner: <span id="tip2"></span>
      </p>
      <p>
        Dinner plus 25% tip: <span id="total"></span>
      </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `span`s to `input`s, and add the `readonly` attribute

```
15% of the Dinner: $<input id="tip" readonly />
<br>
% of the Dinner: <input id="tip2" readonly />%
<br>
Dinner plus 25% tip: $<input id="total" readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

## Add Style:

```
<style>
   
#total, #tip2, #tip{
border : solid 1px black;
padding: 5px;
}

</style>
```

```css
#total, #tip2, #tip{
    border : solid 1px black;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Tip Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
    </header>
    <form action="javascript:void(calc())">
        Cost of the Dinner: $<input id="bill" type="text">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate Tip">
        <br><br>
        15% of the Dinner: <span id="tip">Loading</span>
        <br><br>
        25% of the Dinner: <span id="tip2">Loading</span>
        <br><br>
        Dinner plus 25% tip: <span id="total">Loading</span>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    function calc() {
        var bill = Number(document.getElementById('bill').value);
        var tip = bill * .15;
        var tip2= bill * .25;
        var total_bill = bill + tip2;

        document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML= "$"+Number(tip).toFixed(2);
         document.getElementById("tip2").innerHTML= "$"+Number(tip2).toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML= "$"+Number(total_bill).toFixed(2);         
    }
</script>
</body>
```